# Where can I find the gtk-builder-convert script?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, glade, gtkbuilder

I've built a small GUI app for work that uses some `.glade` files for pop-up windows.  Recently, the ground beneath me was shifted - my environment was upgraded.  Newer pyGTK versions require `GTKBuilder` and `.xml` files instead of `Glade` and `.glade` files and now my poor app is broken.

I need to convert the `.glade` file to the newer `.xml` file.  Problem is Glade-3 is not on our system, and I can't find `gtk-builder-convert` on the web.  I've looked at the Gnome GIT Browser, don't know where to start looking or how to search it.

Would anyone be kind enough to point me to the `gtk-builder-convert` python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gtk-builder-convert` is part of GTK and it should already be installed on your system since you have GTK version 2.12 or higher. But if you really can't find it, here it is in the git browser: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtk-builder-convert

Comment: Thanks.  A `which gtk-builder-convert` on my system returns a "Command not found"

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu: install the tools by `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`

but it is now deprecated

Comment: That's only on Ubuntu. The OP didn't say which platform they were on.

Answer (score 0):

It worked on Linux for me using Gtk3+ and Glade3+ installed from conda by following steps.

1. Open your Gtk1+ older glade XML file designed in Glade1+ user interface in Glade3+ user interface.
2. Click on Save button in Glade3+ user interface.
3. Use this command after conda activate **gtk-builder-convert infile outfile**.